# When doing an OData filter on a class with an OpenType it will error if it is an in filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

Using this sample project
https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/ODataOpenTypeSample

All of these filters return the correct results (they return the 1 record that exists)

http://localhost:5000/odata/Accounts?$filter=Address/City%20in%20(%27Redmond%27)

http://localhost:5000/odata/Accounts?$filter=Address/City%20eq%20%27Redmond%27

http://localhost:5000/odata/Accounts?$filter=Address/Country%20eq%20%27US%27

but if I do this filter

http://localhost:5000/odata/Accounts?$filter=Address/Country%20in%20(%27US%27)

it returns this error

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: elementType

```
Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmUtil.CheckArgumentNull<T>(T value, string parameterName)
Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmCollectionType..ctor(IEdmTypeReference elementType)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.InBinder.BindInOperator(InToken inToken, BindingState state)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBinder.BindIn(InToken inToken)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.FilterBinder.BindFilter(QueryToken filter)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilterImplementation(string filter, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)
Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseFilter()
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.CreateAndValidateQueryOptions(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryContext queryContext)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<OnActionExecuted>b__3(ODataQueryContext queryContext)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Func<Type, IEdmModel> modelFunction, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func<ODataQueryContext, ODataQueryOptions> createQueryOptionFunction)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func<Type, IEdmModel> modelFunction, Func<ODataQueryContext, ODataQueryOptions> createQueryOptionFunction, Action<HttpStatusCode> createResponseAction, Action<HttpStatusCode, string, Exception> createErrorAction)
Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

So my question is are in filters supported on OpenTypes if so is this a bug or is some configuration missing?

Here are a few snipits of code from the sample project listed above.

```
    public class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {
            DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }

        // If a property of the type Dictionary<string, object> is defined, then the containing type is an open type,
        // and the key-value pairs inside this property are called dynamic proerpties.
        public Dictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public Account()
        {
            DynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }

        // If a property of the type Dictionary<string, object> is defined, then the containing type is an open type,
        // and the key-value pairs inside this property are called dynamic proerpties.
        public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        if (_edmModel == null)
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Account>("Accounts");
            builder.EnumType<Gender>();

            builder.Namespace = typeof(Account).Namespace;

            _edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        }

        return _edmModel;
    }
```

City is a defined property and eq filters and in filters work with it.  Country is a part of the dynamic properties dictionary and an "in" is not working when filtering.